# Gerenciador de layout para displays OLED

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, display

Estou trabalhando em um projeto envolvendo as tecnologias `Python3.x`, `Raspberry pi` e dysplays `OLED`. Porém há diversos displays cada qual com diferentes resoluções e gama de cores e eu não quero implementar a mesma funcionalidade para cada um. Eu preciso de alguma biblioteca que permita com que eu escreva uma aplicação para um determinado OLED e essa aplicação rode em outros displays sem que eu precise alterar o código da já existente.

Gostaria também de utilizar um gerenciador de layouts para as aplicações... há algum para displays OLED?

Comment: acho difícil uma solução genérica, pois cada display tem os drivers específicos, desde que você trabalhe com o mesmo tipo de display só mude o tamanho.